# Changing default in Outlook 2013 calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

My boss has shared his calendar with me and I can see the calendars of multiple conference rooms.  Whenever I leave and return to my calendars, I always return to the calendar i viewed last.  As a result, too many times I have scheduled meetings from the wrong calendar.  My question: can i set my Outlook calendar to always go to MY calendar, not the calendar i was previously viewing?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your default sending calendar to yours, that should fix the problem. Hopefully you have enough rights to perform the registry change below. Be creating this regkey, when you send an invite, an email, Outlook will be using the default account, which is yours.

> Out of the box, Outlook 2010 SP1 and Outlook 2013 use the default account for Send to commands but not for new messages created while viewing a pst file (when a POP account is assigned to the pst file), unless you set a registry value to always force the use of the default account. To force all new messages to use the default email account, regardless of which pst file you are viewing, browse to the following registry subkey and add a DWORD named NewItemsUseDefaultSendingAccount:

In Outlook 2013, the key is:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Microsoft\​Office\​15.0\​Outlook\​Options\​Mail
- DWORD value: NewItemsUseDefaultSendingAccount
- Value: 1

You can also force it to use your default account:

> This fix is simple, but can get annoying, fast, since it forces the user to select an account every time they send a new message. (Replies and Forwards always use the account the message arrived on.) This might be good for people who use multiple accounts and frequently (accidentally) send using the wrong account, especially if they are sending sensitive documents, as it will almost eliminate accidentally sending email from the wrong account.

In Outlook 2013, the registry key is:

- HKEY_CURRENT_USER\​Software\​Policies\​Microsoft\​Office\​15.0\​outlook\​options
- Value Name: ForceAccountSelection
  Value type: REG_DWORD: 1 for force, 0 to disable.

Source: https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/outlook-2010/multiple-accounts-and-the-default-account/